# Using foreach() and php form and custom fucntion

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a get function that returns items that have been inputted, which works well. This is in the Input class:

```
public static function get($item){
    if(isset($_POST[$item])){
        return $_POST[$item];
    } else if(isset($_GET[$item])){
        return $_GET[$item];
    }
    return '';
    }
```

now I am trying to use it in a `foreach` loop and having some trouble - I think it is because it is not returning the array?

Here is the form snippet:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="inventory_item_id[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="inventory_record_amount[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="inventory_record_orders[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="inventory_record_sales[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Now when I do the following:

```
$invItems = Input::get('inventory_item_id');

foreach($invItems as $a => $b) {
    //some code here
}
```

PhpStorm yells at me saying:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Expected types: array or object, Actual: string.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Could you `var_dump($invItems)` after `$invItems = Input::get('inventory_item_id');`to find what invItems contains?

Comment: Does your method return an array in every case? If not then you will see that error remain there.

Comment: Probably hits the empty string. Otherwise the post value is indeed a string. No other explanation possible as I see it.

Comment: just make sure its really wrapped inside a form tag, is not an empty field

Answer (score 0):

Probably this happens when you enter for the first time in the page. That's because in the first request you don't have any parameter do use GET and you don't load the page with a POST request, so you don't have any array yet.

To avoid this error you cant validate if `$invItems` is a array.

```
$invItems = Input::get('inventory_item_id');
if (is_array($invItems)){
  foreach($invItems as $a => $b) {
     //some code here
  }
}
```